# Python subplots with seaborn or pyplot

Tags: python, subplot

I'm a R programmer learning python and finding the plotting in python much more  difficult than R.

I'm trying to write the following function but haven't been successful. Could anyone help?

```py
import pandas as pd

#example data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'PC1':[-2.2,-2.0,2.04,0.97],
        'PC2':[0.5,-0.6,0.9,-0.5],
        'PC3':[-0.1,-0.2,0.2,0.8],
        'f1':['a','a','b','b'],
        'f2':['x','y','x','y'],
        'f3':['k','g','g','k']
        })

def drawPCA(df,**kwargs):
    """Produce a 1x3 subplots of scatterplot; each subplot includes two PCs with
    no legend, e.g. subplot 1 is PC1 vs PC2. The legend is on the upper middle of 
    the figure.
    Parameters
    ----------
    df: Pandas DataFrame
        The first 3 columns are the PCs, followed by sample characters.
    kwargs
        To specify hue,style,size, etc. if the plotting uses seaborn.scatterplot; 
        or c,s,etc. if using pyplot scatter
    Example
    ----------
    drawPCA(df1, hue="f1")
    drawPCA(df1, c="f1", s="f2") #if plotting uses plt.scatter
    drawPCA(df1, hue="f1", size="f2",style="f3")
    or more varialbes passable to the actual plotting function
    """
```

Comment: I don't understand what `f1` and `f2` represent. Also, what is the x coordinate for each plot? Or do you want to plot `PC1` against `PC2` etc.?

Comment: @MPA, thanks! `f1, f2, f3` are just columns that can be used to used like this:

Comment: @MPA, thanks! `f1, f2, f3` are just columns that can be used like `seaborn.scatterplot(x="PC1",y="PC2", data=df1,style="f1",hue="f2",size="f3")`. Yes, I'd like subplot 1 to be PC1 vs PC2, subplot 2 to be PC1 vs PC3, etc.

Comment: Is [this](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_visualization/seaborn_scatterplot/) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I come up with! Just two question:

1. is there a parameter to set the legend horizontal, instead of using the `ncol`?
2. how to prevent the figure from being displayed when running the function like this?

```py
fig,ax=drawPCA(df1,hue="f1",style="f2",size="f3")
#may do more changing on the figure.
```

Here is the function:

```py
def drawPCA2(df,**kwargs):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    from matplotlib.figure import figaspect

    nUniVals=sum([df[i].unique().size for i in kwargs.values()])
    nKeys=len(kwargs.keys())

    w, h = figaspect(1/3)
    fig1, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3,figsize=(w,h))
    fig1.suptitle("All the PCs")
    sns.scatterplot(x="PC1",y="PC2",data=df,legend=False,ax=axs[0],**kwargs)
    sns.scatterplot(x="PC1",y="PC3",data=df,legend=False,ax=axs[1],**kwargs)
    sns.scatterplot(x="PC2",y="PC3",data=df,ax=axs[2],label="",**kwargs)
    handles, labels = axs[2].get_legend_handles_labels()
    fig1.legend(handles, labels, loc='lower center',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.85), ncol=nUniVals+nKeys)  
    axs[2].get_legend().remove()
    fig1.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.9])    

    return fig1,axs
```

[image]